# Uber API - Making advance booking

Tags: java, uber-api

I can see the advance booking button in Uber Rider app. Is there an API for advance booking?

I am building a travel booking app and would like to book rides like months before the actual travel dates of the customers.

Is it in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uber API's does not support booking scheduled rides upfront right now - so you can't book future trips. You can record scheduled rides via your code somewhere - and when is the time for the ride - you trigger your ride request.

Comment: Any plan to introduce scheduling ride API in 2018.